# initializating map in spring

Tags: spring, dictionary

I am reading a map from some config using spring expression.Now how can i construct a bean out of it.

```
<bean id="xyz"  class= "java.util.Map" >
   <!-- how to pass $xyz to this -->
    <!-- i know how to pass static entries to  it  using entry tag , but how abut map? !-->
</bean>
```

How can i pass my map to bean xyz?

For String following code can be used.

```
<bean id="x" class ="java.util.String >
  <construtor-arg>  $x
   </constructort-arg>
</bean>
```

But  for map there is not constuctor that takes map as inp

Answer (score 4):

Use the Spring util schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


  <bean id="yourBean" class="yourBean">
    <property name="aPrameterOfTypeMapInYourBean">
      <map>
        <entry key="first" value="hallo"/>
        <entry key="second" value="world"/>
        <entry key="third" value="that is easy"/>
        <entry key="forth" value="and hopefully solve your problem"/>

        <entry key="yourParam" value="$x"/>

      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Spring also support merging of collections (`<map>` should have a merge attribute).
Therefore you need to define two maps, and specify the one of them as parent of the other one.

More Details:

- @See [Spring Reference Appendix D.2.2.5 `<util:map>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-map)
- @See [Spring Reference 4.4.2.4 Collections, subsection "Collection merging"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements)

Comment: thanks for replying.But I wnated to know how can i pass a map to a map. I alredy have a map referance a placeholder $x.Now how to pass this placeholder to another map? I explianed how i did it for string.I want to pass entire  map to another map.Can you please help

Comment: That is want "Collection merging" mean.